# Pass by value in Java

Tags: java

I am new to java and I am currently trying to learn how pass by value works. I have a main class called Test and a second class called TestMax. What I am trying to achieve in my code below is to set the value in the main class for the 2 parameters i and j from class TestMax and call the method `max()` by passing the values of the parameters which I have just passed previously.

The output to console should be something like this:

```
The maximum between 2 and 10 is 10.
```

I know the there is something wrong with the way I pass the values to the method `(int res = max(i,j)` but I spent the last 2h to figure out how why this is not working and I can't figure that out.

```
package testproject;
public class Test {
    /** Main method */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestMax pass = new TestMax();
        pass.setI(2);
        pass.setJ(10);
        int res = max(i,j);
        System.out.println("The maximum between " + pass.getI() +
                " and " + pass.getJ() + " is " + res);
    }
}
```

**Second class TestMax:**

```
package testproject;

public class TestMax {

    int i ;
    int j ;

public static int max(int num1, int num2) {

    int result;
    if (num1 > num2)
       result = num1;
    else
       result = num2;

    return result;

}

//Getters & Setters
public void setJ(int j) {
    this.j = j;
}

public int getJ() {
    return j;
}

public void setI(int i) {
    this.i = i;
}

public int getI() {
    return i;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what happens when you run the program. Any compiler errors? Exceptions? No output? I'm asking this because carefully reading compiler errors will usually give you a hint as to what is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference. The problem is this line of code:

```
int res = max(i,j);
```

The values `i` and `j` are out of scope, and `max()` is not in your current class, so you need to use getters to access the values and reference the method through the class, like so:

```
int res = TestMax.max(pass.getI(), pass.getJ());
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
int res = max(i,j);
```

doesn't make sense: neither `max` nor `i` nor `j` has been declared in that scope. Your compiler should reject this.

You must have meant to write:

```
int res = TestMax.max(pass.getI(), pass.getJ());
```

Answer (score 1):

`int res = max(i,j);`

In the above line neither `max()` nor arguments `i and j` has been **declared in that scope.** So its a compilation error.

**You should write it as:**

`int res = TestMax.max(pass.getI(), pass.getJ());`

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the max method so that it is no longer static and instead uses variables i and j as its inputs, like the code below:

```
 ...

    public int max() {
        int result;
        if (i > j)
           result = i;
        else
           result = j;

        return result;
    }

...
```

and now you need to omit the parameters in the following line in your main method:

```
int res = max(i,j);
```

which changes to:

```
int res = max();
```

However, if you change your TestMax class in this way, you need to create a class extending Exception so that you can throw it if someone calls max() method before assigning values to i and j. Another way to avoid this is to build a constructor and get i and j there.